# Convert from string of number into numeric values

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote this function where I can provide worksheet and it should convert the first column into numeric values from a string. but when I called the function from a sub, it doesn't do the job.

```
 Function ConvertTextToNumber(Worksheet As Worksheet)      
 If (Worksheet.Name = "TB") Or (Worksheet.Name = "JE") Then
        [A:A].Select
        With Selection
            .NumberFormat = "General"
            .Value = .Value
        End With
    ElseIf Worksheet.Name = "GLACCOUNT1100" Then
        [D:D].Select
        With Selection
            .NumberFormat = "General"
            .Value = .Value
        End With
    End If
End Function
```

then i called it inside this sub

```
Sub Select_Global_Account()
Dim length As Long, i As Long
Dim Start_range As Long, End_range As Long

' range input for the account number
Start_range = shStart.Range("P25").Value
End_range = shStart.Range("S25").Value

'================== converToNumber the acount column
Call helper.ConvertTextToNumber(shTB)
'===================

Call Iterate_In_Range(Start_range, End_range)
' JE report
Call JEReport.JEReport
' GL report
Call GL1100.AmountDate
```

the rest of the code works fine, only the helper.ConvertTextToNumber(shTB) doesnt change the text to string

Comment: It isn't clear here why you need "helper." when you call it?

Have you tried just running "Call ConvertTextToNumber(shTB)" without "helper."?

Comment: helper just a module name. just a keep module name, i keeps all the helping functions there

Comment: It might be worth showing your definition of the "shTB" variable for clarity

Comment: it is just a worksheet with many columns, where the first columns values are text :Account
0500
0503
0504
0505
0506
0507
0508 they are strings instead of numbvers

Comment: You dont specify what sheet you are acting on, `[A:A].Select` you pass it in, but just check it's name.

Comment: i didn't get you, i just prove the worksheet in the parameter.  can you please make it more clear. also in the if statement i mentioned the name of the TB. can give an example?

Comment: @ Spainey  it gets to wark thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this code. Observe that `Value = Value` can't change a string to a number. Therefore the code below first extracts the numeric value of `Value` and then assigns that new value to the cell.

```
 Function ConvertTextToNumber(Ws As Worksheet)

    ' please don't use variable names that might
    ' confuse either you or Excel or both

    Dim Clm As Long
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim Cell As Range

    With Ws
        Select Case Ws.Name
            Case "TB", "JE"
                Clm = 1                         ' column A
            Case "GLACCOUNT1100"
                Clm = 4                         ' column D
            Case Else
                Exit Sub
        End Select

        ' convert cell from row 2 to the last used cell
        Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(2, Clm), .Cells(.Rows.Count, Clm).End(xlUp))
        For Each Cell In Rng
            .Value = Val(.Value)
            .NumberFormat = "General"
        Next Cell
    End With
End Function
```

I have added code to instruct what to do if the worksheet passed as argument doesn't qualify.

Comment: You are setting `Clm` but I don't see what you are doing with it?

Comment: Sorry about that. I normally assign column numbers to a variable `C`. Here I chose `Clm` for the sake of better transparency and then forgot. I corrected the error in this line `Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(2, Clm), .Cells(.Rows.Count, Clm).End(xlUp))`